# A polynomial approval

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I prove this expression mathematically?
$$\prod_{i=1}^n (\theta x_i+(1-\theta)y_i)^{p_i} \ge{\theta {\prod_{i=1}^n}  x_i^{p_i}} +(1-\theta){\prod_{i=1}^n}y_i^{p_i}$$ for $$ 0\le\theta\le1  \quad ,\quad 0\le{p_i}\le1 \quad ,\quad\sum_1^n {p_i}=1\quad ,\quad \forall x_i,y_i\in \Re \quad ,\quad x_i,y_i\gt0 $$ to me it is evident but I don't know how to prove it. Thank you!

Comment: I think you also want your $x_i$ and $y_i$ to be non-negative, right?

Comment: Can you prove it for $n=1$?

Comment: Is it evident as a [freshman's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream), or for some other reason involving $\displaystyle1=\sum_1^n {p_i} ?$

Comment: *Nothing* that you can't prove is evident. Ever.

Comment: The second derivative of $x^p$ is $p(p-1)x^{p-2}$. For $0<p<1$, $p(p-1)x^{p-2}<0$ on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: How do you define $x_i^{p_i}$ for $x_i<0$?

Comment: both $x_i $ and $y_i$ are non-negative.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=x^p$ for $0 \leq p \leq 1$ and $x \geq 0$.
Then by Jensen's inequality, for all $0 \leq \theta \leq 1$ and $x,y \geq 0$:
$$ f(\theta x+(1-\theta)y) \geq \theta f(x)+(1-\theta)f(y)$$
since $f$ is concave. The inequality follows by multiplying out, ignoring all terms with $x_i y_j$ in them (since they are non-negative - reasonably, all $x_i$ and $y_i$ must be in this context).

Comment: actually in order to approve concavity of $f(x)=x^p $ I need this approval.

Comment: The second derivative is non-positive everywhere. That implies concavity.